# use library (gcc) in matlab and error with compile of mex

Tags: matlab, gcc, compiler-errors, mex, osx-yosemite

I am using Mac OSX (yosemite V 10.10.1) and running MATLAB 2014a  on it.

I wanted to use SPAM library (sparse modeling software by J. Mairal) on MATLAB and for that I have to install XCode6.1 (that has gcc). First I type in command window `mex -setup` and result is shown below:

```
mex -setup
MEX configured to use 'Xcode with Clang' for C language compilation.

Warning: The MATLAB C and Fortran API has changed to support MATLAB
     variables with more than 2^32-1 elements. In the near future
     you will be required to update your code to utilize the
     new API. You can find more information about this at:
     http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/upgrading-mex-files-to-use-64-bit-api.html.

To choose a different language, select one from the following:
 mex -setup C++ 
 mex -setup FORTRAN
```

So after that I run the `compile.m` file in SPAM library and suddenly I saw an error that was:

```
add_flag =
 -mmacosx-version-min=10.6
Warning: Directory already exists. 
> In compile at 144 
compilation of: -I./linalg/ -I./decomp/ -I./prox/ -I./dictLearn/ dictLearn/mex/mexArchetypalAnalysis.cpp
Building with 'Xcode Clang++'.
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fopenmp'
Error using mex
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/'
ld: library not found for -lgomp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Error in compile (line 439)
    mex(args{:});
```

I don't understand what to do. please help me!

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the actual error is occurring at the point of linking with precompiled libraries. The 2 issues are as follows:

1. The compile code apparently included in the `compile.m` file looks like it is intended to compile with gcc (it is trying to include files installed by GCC, possibly even linux-specific ones, are you sure that it's an OSX-compatible toolbox?), and yet the error strongly suggests that you are in fact using clang to compile it - you will either need to change the compiler (easy) or rewrite `compile.m` (not so easy).
2. One of the libraries that the code needs to have installed in order to be properly linked hasn't been found. On OSX I think this file should be called `libgomp.dylib` (any mac afficionados want to confirm this?). If you have it on your computer, then it's not in a directory that clang is looking in. You can confirm the library is installed by running `find / | grep libgomp.dylib` from the terminal - if it is there, you can add it into the compiler argument in `compile.m` using the `-I /DIRECTORY_HOLDING_LIBRARY` syntax.

It is entirely possible that fixing 1. will also remediate 2. - I have never tried using SPAM